# How do you create a conditional nesting formula on excel 2010 with more than 3 conditions?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have "A, B, C and D." I need " if a>0, use a, otherwise, use b. If b has the error "#N/A", use c, otherwise use b. If c=0, use d/61, otherwise use c.

So far, I have this:

```
=IF(DB11>0,DB11,IF(ISNA(DA11),CZ11,IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11)))
```

Where:
DB11 = 0 (A), DA11 = #N/A (B), CZ11 = 138 (C) and BE11 = 6000 (D)

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php) will help you better understand nesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think rewording your conditions may help you see where you've gone wrong. Think of it this way instead:

```
If `a>0`, then `a`. Otherwise, check if `b=#N/A`.
  If `b=#N/A`, then check if `c=0`. Otherwise, `b`.
    If `c=0`, then `d/61`. Otherwise, `c`.
```

Note the difference between the first line and what you described. You jumped straight to "use `b`" and then checked that `b` met a condition after you already said to use it. This won't work in a nested conditional statement. If you conclude something, then it's done; no other conditions are checked.

To illustrate this, consider the case where `a=0`, `b=#N/A`, `c=0`, and `d=61`. You expect this to result in `1`. Evaluating your formula would go as follows:

```
=IF(0>0,DB11,IF(ISNA(DA11),CZ11,IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11)))
=IF(FALSE,DB11,IF(ISNA(DA11),CZ11,IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11)))
=IF(ISNA(DA11),CZ11,IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11))
=IF(ISNA(#N/A),CZ11,IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11))
=IF(TRUE,CZ11,IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11))
=CZ11
=0
```

Since the check of the condition on `b` concludes with `c`, the condition on `c` is never even checked. This is the source of your error.

Here's how your formula should be constructed.

```
=IF(DB11>0,DB11,IF(ISNA(DA11),IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11),DA11))
```

To illustrate how this works, look at the same example case as above.

```
=IF(0>0,DB11,IF(ISNA(DA11),IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11),DA11))
=IF(FALSE,DB11,IF(ISNA(DA11),IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11),DA11))
=IF(ISNA(DA11),IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11),DA11)
=IF(ISNA(#N/A),IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11),DA11)
=IF(TRUE,IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11),DA11)
=IF(CZ11=0,BE11/61,CZ11)
=IF(0=0,BE11/61,CZ11)
=IF(TRUE,BE11/61,CZ11)
=BE11/61
=61/61
=1
```

Comment: Just a comment: Very often, formulas that are too long/complex to wrap your head around can be simplified by breaking them up and putting intermediate results into additional columns.